# jQuery addClass not working on elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, vivagraphjs

I have an array of DOM elements and I am trying to iterate through them and add a class using jQuery, but jQuery does not seem to be setting the class with the addClass method. However, the attr function still works. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my results from the console.

[image: jQuery addclass not working]

http://jsfiddle.net/kf77m/1/

```
line 64
$(ui).addClass("class", "js-tooltip");
```

Comment: Let's begin with not posting the actual code in your question and providing a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TTzZD/ Since it's an `svg` element, you can't manipulate it the same as you would a DOM element. I don't believe `svg`s are technically in the `dom`, rather they are sub-documents to the current document with their own namespaces and whatnot.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Sorry, couldn't find a way to get the Vivagraph code on a CDN. Question updated

Comment: Compare the results that you get between calling `.className` and `.getAttribute()` using an `svg` and `html` element: http://jsfiddle.net/TTzZD/2/ I imagine jQuery doesn't support or understand the alternate `svg` response from `rect.className`. This is just an alternate way you have to work with `svg` elements: Use `svg.setAttribute()` and `svg.getAttribute()`.

Comment: (Also note you can "hack" jsfiddle to add includes to the head [using the `css` window](http://jsfiddle.net/TTzZD/4/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eithedog beat me to posting, jQuery uses `element.className`. The issue is that SVG elements treat the `element.className` value as `readonly`, meaning jQuery's attempt to set the class does nothing:

```
if ( elem.className !== finalValue ) {
    elem.className = finalValue;
}
```

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L46

`RECT` elements implement the `SVGRectElement` interface:

```
interface SVGRectElement : SVGElement,
                           SVGTests,
                           SVGLangSpace,
                           SVGExternalResourcesRequired,
                           SVGStylable,
                           SVGTransformable {
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength x;
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength y;
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength width;
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength height;
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength rx;
  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedLength ry;
};
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#InterfaceSVGRectElement

`SVGRectElement` implement `SVGStylable`, which includes this little tidbit:

```
className (readonly SVGAnimatedString)
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGStylable

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [jquery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js) I'd attribute this behavior to this #8317:

`elem.className = finalValue;`

<strike>Seeing that SVG elements don't have this property, the class won't be set (or - the particular line will still run, it will just not do anything)</strike>

See the comments for more info!

Comment: Here is a better link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L46

Comment: Also, the statement about the *SVG elements don't have this property*; [they do](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGStylable), they just don't operate the same way, e.g., *className (**readonly** SVGAnimatedString)*.

Comment: @JaredFarrish oh, I was sure the property doesn't exist - per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/class . Good point!

Comment: What you were probably looking for was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGRectElement, which references [`SVGStylable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGStylable), which explains `element.className` as in the standard.

Comment: @JaredFarrish nah - it was more of "working with setting attributes on SVG elements some years ago and remembering the issue with classes" combined with "checking the reference in the first reference link, which being mozilla, tends to be correct most of the time" ;)